# VBA: Print shapes in sheets2 from sheets1 code - Selection

Tags: vba, selection, shapes

Based on the button click from sheets 1 where the code is written, I want to add a a shape on sheets 2 and using the Select changing some shape properties as shown in the following code.

```
With Sheets(2).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 800, 700, 60, 60).Select
 Selection.Text = "Shape"
 Selection.Font.Size = 26
End With
```

Isn't it supposed to select the sheets 2 and print the shape as well change its properties? Or when I do the Selection is it trying to find the value from sheets 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
Sheets(2).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeOval, 800, 700, 60, 60).Select
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Shape"
Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = 26
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy. Although I tried again and did it, I can't understand why I need the TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text since I did it with only Selection.Text

Comment: However, if I place Selection.Text = "Shape" also works.